# set header in camel route with bean ref

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

```
 from("direct:myRoute1")
                .bean(new DemoRoute(), "test(Demo,xxx)")
                .end();


 from("direct:myRoute2")
                .bean(new DemoRoute(), "test(Demo,xxx)")
                .end(); 



public interface Shape

@Component
class Circle implements Shape{
}

@Component
class Square implements Shape{}
```

I want to inject the Shape implementation in route `test(Demo,xxx)`

1. Can setHeader() help to add a Shape implementation in route.
2. Can there be an alternative apart from setting header in camel route as it has its pros and cons

[Pros and Cons of setting Lot of headers in Camel Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438269/pros-and-cons-of-setting-lot-of-headers-in-camel-exchange)

Comment: the cons of setting headers in Camel Exchange are against setting a lot of headers and getting and updating them very often that can conduct to a performance issue because they are stored in the Treemap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to bypass Camel :

Since you are instanciating the bean yourself and not relying on spring to manage it, you could pass the Shape implementation through a constructor.

Add a Shape field in your DemoRoute class:

```
public class DemoRoute {

        private  final Shape shape;


        public DemoRoute(Shape shape) {
            this.shape = shape;
        }

        // test method that uses shape
    }
```

And in your Route config class, configure as follow :

```
@Component
public class CustomRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private final Square square;
    private final Circle circle;

    CustomRoute(Square square, Circle circle){
      this.square = square;
      this.circle = circle;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:myRoute1")
                .bean(new DemoRoute(circle), "test(Demo,xxx)")
                .end();


        from("direct:myRoute2")
                .bean(new DemoRoute(square), "test(Demo,xxx)")
                .end();
    }
}
```